# Not able to import oracle dump with hindi font data properly

Tags: unicode, oracle11g, character-encoding, migration, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm stuck on one problem and it is that while importing oracle dump, I'm not able to restore hindi font data properly even when character set is same for source and destination. So is there any solution where i can restore Oracle dump with hindi font data in a proper way? I'm using oracle 11g enterprise edition.

I am using the following command to import dump file in oracle :

$impdp system/*** schemas=BANK directory=BANK dumpfile=FULLDB_01052021.DMP logfile=BANK.log

So the rows count get match after the import. But the data with in the Hindi font comes with some junk values which is  आदमी&#2344 exp  but it should be 'आदमीन exp'  for the junk values.
See the attachament [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGpMC.jpg)

Comment: Just saying _"I'm not able to restore hindi font data properly..."_ is too vague. You need to update your question to provide much more detail on the specific problem you are facing. What happens when you do the restore? How are you doing it? What error do you get? etc...

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. Find out what the old database uses and how it wrote the dump, then either use the same encoding or convert while importing.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for response. But for both source and destination the V$NLS_PARAMETERS are same so the encoding is same for both..